# Do I keep gear from a dismissed soldier?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've noticed that I can dismiss soldiers which removes them from my game. What happens to the items that they might be wearing when they are dismissed?

If I was to dismiss a Colonel soldier in Titan armour, would I lose the armour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The items the soldiers are wearing will go back to the pool of inventory. On a sidenote, dismissing as an option is due to the fact that soldier's Will will permanently decreased if the soldier was constantly critically wounded in battle.

Comment: Note this will not happen if you dismiss an interceptor - you will lose the weapon. Initiate rearming with Avalanches before dismissing it.

Comment: Personally, I use dismiss because I got 10 heavies and no snipers...